# How do I access the child element of a Frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling, frame

I have frames in my main window which are set to visible/collapsed based on user input:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
           <Frame Name="InputsFrame" Source="Inputs.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Visibility="Visible" 
                   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
    </ScrollViewer>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Frame Name="LoadCasesFrame" Source="LoadCases.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Visibility="Collapsed"
                   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
    </ScrollViewer>

    <!-- etc -->

</Grid>
```

The Inputs.xaml frame basically just consists of a 3rd party DoubleTextBox control (over 100 of them), and the user can just enter in values to that page. C# code behind:

```
private void InputsTab_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    LoadCasesFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ScrollViewer2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    InputsFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ScrollViewer1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

In this main window, there is a menu on top to allow for saving and opening the file. When I open the file, I want the data to be read (which I am able to do successfully) and also for the UI in the Inputs.xaml file to be updated.

The following code is in Inputs.xaml.cs:

```
public void LoadValues()
{
    List<DoubleTextBox> dtb1 = App.GetLogicalChildCollection<DoubleTextBox>(inputsGrid);

    for (int i = 0; i < dtb1.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach (var keyValuePair in App.globalDictionary)
        {
            var doubleTextBox = dtb1[i] as DoubleTextBox;

            if (doubleTextBox.Name == keyValuePair.Key)
            {
                doubleTextBox.Value = 500;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function works (all the values in the GUI update to 500) when I call it from the Inputs.xml.cs page (for example, when I put it in the `Page_Loaded` event). However, I need to call this function from the `MainWindow`, since that is where the event handler for the Open File event is located:

```
private void openProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string stringToDeserialize = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
        App.DeserializeJSONString(stringToDeserialize);
    }

    // call LoadValues here
}
```

Calling `LoadValues()` above doesn't update the GUI in the Input.xaml page. I originally had something like this in my `MainWindow`:

```
Inputs _inputs = new Inputs();
_inputs.LoadValues();
```

I know that the problem is that I have created a new object for `Inputs` and that's probably why it's not working. I'm unsure how to do it so that I don't use a new object -- wonder if I could use the `InputsFrame` somehow. I've also tried using event handlers to no success.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: For future reference, please try to constrain the problem description to only the bare essentials required to understand the question, and ensure that the question title accurately describes the _primary_ issue at hand (rather than e.g. some particular strategy for work-around you tried). In the above, I feel confident that the discussion regarding the file-opening is not relevant; it serves only to obscure the main question being asked.

Comment: JohnSaunders & @PeterDuniho: Thank you for your comments and edits. I tried to be as clear and simple as possible. I will keep your advice in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interact with the `Inputs` object that is in your `Frame` element, you need to retrieve that one, not create a new one.

You can do that like this:

```
((Inputs)InputsFrame.Content).LoadValues();
```

I.e. the `Contents` property of the `Frame` returns a reference to the `Inputs` object that is used to populate the `Frame`. Just cast that to `Inputs` to access the appropriate members of that class, such as `LoadValues()`.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. This worked a charm. Wasn't aware that frames could be accessed in this way.